# How to get next() to occur in Express callback returning a Bluebird Promise?

Tags: express, bluebird

```
exports.verifyReCAPTCHA = function(req, res, next) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let recaptcha = new Recaptcha(process.env.RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY, process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY, recaptchaData);
    recaptcha.verify((success, error_code) => {
      if (success) {
        return resolve()
      }
      return reject(next(new Error(error_code)))
    })
    return reject(next(new Error('Unknown error occured!')))
  })
}
```

I've left `recaptchaData` undefined purposefully to see whether the returned errors would pass through to next(), but they don't. It simply gives me an unhandled Promise rejection error and the response doesn't go through to the next callback, which would send a request with status 500 and the error message.

```
app.post('/contact/send', contact.verifyReCAPTCHA, contact.send);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middleware usage is *not correct* You don't return a `Promise` from a middleware because `express` will not call `.then` of you. Looks like you're trying to chain the middleware. Here's how you can do it:

```
exports.verifyReCAPTCHA = function(req, res, next) {
  let recaptcha = new Recaptcha(process.env.RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY, process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY, recaptchaData);
  recaptcha.verify((success, error_code) => {
    if (success) {
      return next(); // <-- calling next(), go to next middleware
    }
    return next(new Error(error_code))
  })
  next(new Error('Unknown error occured!')) // <-- not sure where this is originating from, try..catch perhaps?
}
```